# Best way to implement a non-blocking wait?

Tags: python, multithreading

In python, if I want to keep a process or thread running **forever**, I can typically do this with an empty while loop:

```
while 1:
    pass
```

This, however, will eat an unfair amount of CPU process. Adding a short `sleep` would work:

```
import time
while 1:
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Is there any best or cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: What is the thread waiting for? Why don't you do time.sleep(1000000)?

Comment: it's for a server-like application, so i'd like it to wait for more than days (1000000 seconds)!
theoretically a thread that has to run _forever_ has to keep running for a much longer time than _a very high number of seconds_

Comment: Is the thread doing *anything useful* other than sleeping or busy-looping? If not, can you just do away with it? And if it *is* doing something worthwhile, 'fess up! That's the bit that we need to know about to help you.

Comment: it is not doing a thing apart from keeping the process running so that its subprocesses can keep working

Comment: I doubt that this is necessary since subprocesses can be detached from their parent processes. However, `while True: time.sleep(0x7FFFFFFF)` should work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given the rather bizarre requirements (a process that goes forever without using much CPU), this is reasonably compact:

```
import threading
dummy_event = threading.Event()
dummy_event.wait()
```

...however, I fear I am succumbing to the temptation to solve your Y and not your X.

Besides which, this won't work if your platform doesn't provide the `threading` module. If you try to substitute the `dummy_threading` module, `dummy_event.wait()` returns immediately.

**Update:** if you are just keeping a parent process going for the sake of its subprocesses, you can use the [`wait()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)method on [Popen objects](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects), or the [`join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) method on [`Process`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#process-and-exceptions) objects. Both of these methods will block indefinitely until the subprocess ends. If you're using some other subprocess API, there's bound to be equivalent functionality available. If not, get the PID of the process and use [`os.waitpid()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.waitpid).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use busy waiting. Depending on what you are waiting for, use one of the operating system's blocking wait functions, e.g. `select` on Unix and `WaitForSingleObject`/`WaitForMultipleObjects` on Windows.

Comment: thanks for the answer. though, i'm not waiting for a thing. as the question implies, the process aim is to run _forever_ until it's killed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are relying on this script to perform periodic maintenance, use cron (UNIX) or scheduled tasks (Windows).

If you wish to wait for subprocesses to complete, use `os.waitpid`.

If you wish to wait for filesystem activity, use [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

What's the issue with sleeping for a very brief period of time? 1 millisecond is close to an eternity to a modern computer. Provided you don't have thousands of these threads (which it sounds like you don't), then there is NOTHING wrong with sleeping for one, ten, ten thousand, or ten million milliseconds every iteration through the loop. The CPU won't even notice this little blip.

Comment: Bad practice to wait with a while loop. Your answer is similar to “what’s wrong with a tiny burning car tire for a short period of time?”. If there weren’t any other options. But there are. Plenty. And the question was for a cleaner way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

Someone might end up to this old question so I'll be leaving this here.
The optimal way is a [BlockingScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/schedulers/blocking.html#apscheduler.schedulers.blocking.BlockingScheduler) from [apscheduler](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler) module with which you also get to schedule jobs in regular intervals (or cron like or whatever)

```
from datetime import datetime
import os

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler


def tick():
    print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=3)
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30019349)

Comment: I'll edit the comment asap thanks