# What Python Module Should I Use For Updating?

Tags: python, module

Alright I've been using the time module for time.sleep(x) function for awhile... but I need something that won't pause the shell and so the user can continue using the program while it's counting.

To be more "specific" let's suppose I had a program that needed to wait 5 seconds before executing a function. In this time using the time.sleep() function the user can't type anything into the shell because it's sleeping. However, I need Python to "count the 5 seconds" in the background while the user is able to use the shell. Is this possible?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but sounds like you need a thread.

Comment: This might be relevant to your interests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226628/non-blocking-wait-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) ? You should handle piece of your work in one worker and another separate worker where you would count or sleep with time.sleep

Here is an example that might help you understand and use threading with time.sleep

```
import threading
import time

def sleeper():
    print 'Starting to sleep'
    time.sleep(10)
    print 'Just waking up..'
    print 'snooze'
    print 'oh no. I have to get up.'

def worker():
    print 'Starting to work'
    time.sleep(1) # this also a work. :)
    print 'Done with Work'

t = threading.Thread(name='sleeper', target=sleeper)
w = threading.Thread(name='worker', target=worker)

w.start()
t.start()
```

Comment: Okay, before I accept your answer... I need to know one more thing.. I was looking at the examples of the threading module and I tried to use this one:def hello():print "hello, world"

t = Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start() # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed                                                                             But this didn't work because it couldn't find the Subclass timer module. Any ideas on why?

Comment: I added a easy to understand example for you. :)  Yeah Timer could be used in similar effect too. Timer is a subclass of thread and straightforward to implement a delayed parallel execution. Thanks.